# Do I need DELL OpenManage to generate snmp traps on RAID degradation?

Tags: dell, hardware-raid, snmp, surveillance, dell-openmanage

I need to setup surveillance on all our servers to spot any RAID degradation in time. However, not all of our servers have OpenManage installed, and since they are in production I don't like the idea of installing it on them.

Therefor: Is it necessary to have it installed in order to get an event-log for any degradation of the RAID? Because, if I get an event-log I can send an SNMP trap, if I understand it correctly.

I thought it was the driver that responsible for the event-logging, but on a machine that recently had a degradation, I can't seem to find any log event for it.

EDIT: this is for a Windows enviroment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minimal OpenManage Linux Installation for SNMP Raid Monitoring? ](http://serverfault.com/questions/141489/minimal-openmanage-linux-installation-for-snmp-raid-monitoring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMSA is needed, unless you have a more conclusive management system in place, which would support PERC/CERCs